# Get quantity attribute in products list page

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

[image: quantity attribute]

I'm using magento 2.
I want to get this attribute in products list page. Does anyone show me how ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You need define new observer

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_collection_load_after">
        <observer name="Your_Module_Add_Quantity" instance="Your\Module\Observer\AddQuantityToCollectionObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

With code like

```
namespace Your\Module\Observer;
class AddQuantityToCollectionObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Add information about product Quantity to collection
     * Used for product collection after load
     *
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $productCollection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore($productCollection->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId();
        foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
            $productId = $product->getId();
            $stockStatus = $this->stockRegistryProvider->getStockStatus($productId, $websiteId);
            $product->setQty($stockStatus->getQty());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
        echo $StockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
?>
```

Comment: Please consider adding more info on your answer.